# Subclipse installation and setup

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have used `Subclipse` in the past, but never did a complete install and setup on my own. I have tried to follow the instructions on several websites but I just cannot seem to get it to work. I have it installed in eclipse, and I have an account on Tigris, but I can't figure out how to create a new project to share. I need assistance starting from adding a new repository in eclipse. I am new to the whole thing from an install POV so please be as thorough as possible. I have a project for one of my classes that requires us to use SVN to work on on a group project, so I need to get this up and running. I have a Macbook Pro with Mountain Lion OSX if that helps any.

**Edit** I am stuck on step 4 [here](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse)  I just don't know how to setup the repository, and get the correct url. I opened an account on the tigris websitE, but under their help menu it says there is a "create new project" link under the "projects" tab... but I don't see one anywhere.

Comment: What instructions have you tried, and why didn't it work?  What were you expecting to see and what happened instead?

Comment: Try restarting eclipse with -clean option.

Comment: Do you have a subversion repo you can point at?

Comment: Can you try this http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA.

Comment: If you use windows, you can use http://www.visualsvn.com/ for easy server setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing Subversion server and repository then you just take the option to Add a SVN Repository and you enter the URL for the repository.

If you need to create a repository, you can only do it locally on your hard drive.  There is an option on the view drop down menu labelled New Repository ... this will let you specify a local folder where it will create a new repository and add a connection to that repository.